# myContract.getPastEvents("allEvents") returns empty array

Tags: web3js, events, ropsten, abi

I want to get all past events from a contract I deployed on the Ropsten network.

Contract is:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;

contract SampleContract {
    uint storageData;

    event MamboNumberTwo(uint _value);
    event MamboNumberFive(uint _value);
    event MamboNumberString(string _value);

    function test(uint x, uint y, string memory s) public {
        emit MamboNumberTwo(x);
        emit MamboNumberFive(y);
        emit MamboNumberString(s);
    }
}
```

It is deployed at [0xdd73A24Ef263D9bed42b0db60607F915194A7fbF](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xdd73A24Ef263D9bed42b0db60607F915194A7fbF), as you can see this contract has emitted nine events so far.
I would like to get them using web3's `myContract.getPastEvents("allEvents")`, but this returns a Promise resolving in an empty array, as though no event was emitted yet.

Full code:

```
web3 = new Web3(...) // Connect to Ropsten node via Websocket
var contract = new web3.eth.Contract([...], "0xdd73A24Ef263D9bed42b0db60607F915194A7fbF");
contract.getPastEvents("allEvents").then(console.log);
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a filter to the call with fromblock > 0:

```
contract.getPastEvents("allEvents", { fromBlock: 1}).then(console.log);
```

Comment: This raises 'Error: Returned error: leveldb: not found'

Comment: I was working with web3-1.0.0beta34, works fine with beta55. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty counter-intuitive since web3 says it's optional...